# Django gerando código estranho

Tags: html, python, django, django-templates

Estou usando o visual studio community e criei um projeto Web com Django, porém ao fazer a página inicial, está me gerando este código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o código que eu tenho é este:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>{{ title }}</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/content/materialize.css' %}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/content/app.css' %}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    </head>
    <body>
```

alguém sabe porque ao executar, ele faz isso? esculhamba o html?

isso está criando um espaço na minha página que não deveria ter.

código que renderiza:

```
def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        {
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )
```

Comment: Verifica se o seu documento html (o arquivo do template) tem algum caractere null (com Regex em um editor de texto avançado pode achar digitando `\0`), pode ser isto. Verifique também se salvou todos documento em UTF8.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, os documentos estão em utf-8 e não tem caracter null, tentei deixando o documento totalmente em branco sem nada, nem as tag básica do html e da a mesma coisa...

Comment: Tem certeza que o template que está sendo renderizado é o seu? Não sei como o Visual Studio faz, mas talvez ele esteja renderizando um template dele próprio e incluindo o seu como *conteúdo* da página (i.e. colocando tudo no body do template "pai"). Como é o código que renderiza e retorna esse template? (i.e. a view)

Comment: @mgibsonbr, acrescentei na pergunta.. acho estranho porque o modelo que vem no visual studio funciona certo, ele não quebra o html, ae eu so alterei o conteúdo da página inicial e começo a dar essas loucuras...

Comment: É melhor dar `CTRL+U`... A nova atualização do chrome mostra  umas paradas estranhas no `Console`

Comment: Você usou o Notepad do Windows para fazer essa edição? (veja [essa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6543595/520779), me pergunte se quiser mais detalhes) A propósito, há uma diferença entre o HTML recebido de fato do servidor (que você vê pela função "ver código-fonte" do browser) e o DOM gerado a partir do mesmo (que você vê pela função "inspecionar elemento" ou similar). Sua captura de tela me parece o segundo caso. Veja o que está sendo gerado de fato, se o conteúdo estranho está vindo dentro do `body` (duvido, mas pode ser) ou no início do arquivo (acho mais provável).

Comment: @mgibsonbr, isso mesmo, troquei a codifficação para utf-8 sem BOM e funciono... agora fica a duvida.. será que terei que fazer isso para os proximos arquivos que criarei?

Comment: @MeuChapeu Receio que sim... A menos que você use algum outro editor de texto que use (ou possa ser configurado para) por padrão UTF-8 sem BOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código `&#65279;` corresponde ao caractere Unicode `U+FEFF`, muito usado nas codificações UTF-16 como "marca de ordem dos bytes" (BOM). Entretanto, alguns editores de texto (como o Notepad do Windows) colocam esse BOM mesmo em arquivos UTF-8, que não precisam de BOM (já que a ordem dos bytes é sempre a mesma). Isso é feito provavelmente com a intenção de "marcar" o arquivo como UTF-8, embora essa prática seja desencorajada.

Como seu arquivo modificado tinha esse caractere no início do arquivo, ele foi enviado ao browser junto com o resto, e as regras de *parsing* do browser determinaram que ele deveria fazer parte do conteúdo da mesma. Pela robustez/tolerância a falhas dos algoritmos usuais de *parsing* de HTML, o fato de não ter um `html` e `body` não os impede de aceitar o conteúdo - colocando-os pra você. Assim, o DOM resultante terminou com um `head` vazio e tudo o que estava no seu template dentro do `body` criado automaticamente.

A forma ideal de corrigir isso é retirando o BOM dos seus arquivos. Alternativamente, *talvez* seja possível fazer com que o próprio browser ignore esse BOM, informando a ele no `content_type` que o arquivo está codificado como "UTF-8 com BOM" (que se não me engano é `UTF-8Y`):

```
resposta = render(
    request,
    'app/index.html',
    {
        'title':'Home Page',
        'year':datetime.now().year,
    }
)
resposta.charset = "UTF-8Y"
return resposta
```

(não tenho como testar nesse momento se a solução acima será aceita pelos principais browsers, então sugiro usá-las somente como última opção)

Fontes: [essas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9691771/520779) [três](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6538203/520779) [perguntas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23700200/520779) no SOen.